# How to apply android:listSelector style via theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

I created a few drawables to handle state colors, etc for list view items. These work when I set the android:listSelector property to them on the list definition in the layout. But, I'd like to apply them globally, so in my theme, I declared the style, like:

```
<style name="QFListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/listview_selector</item>
</style>
```

Why doesn't this work, or, what should I be doing to get it to work?

Answer (score -1):

Android first draws the ListView background as well as the dividers. Then, the system draws the list selector. Finally, ListView renders all itemviews on top of that. Thanks to this diagram, it is clear the list selector will never be visible with opaque background set to itemviews.

Read this : #Customizing itemviews background

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/08/08/listview-tips-tricks-3-create-fancy-listviews/

Comment: it works when I set it directly on the list view itself, so that's not the problem. It doesn't work via over riding the attribute via a custom style within the theme the app is using.

Comment: What background you have set to ListView??

Comment: I don't see the relevance, but, none; there's nothing set on the background. Again, if I apply the drawable to the list view within the layout, like android:listSelector=""@drawable/listview_selector" it works great. It doesn't work when over riding the android:listSelector attribute in the custom style within my app's custom theme.

Comment: can you set the background of the listview to transparent : @android:color/transparent

Comment: The question isn't whether or not the drawable works. The question is why isn't it being applied via the style. Going through each of the list views to set the background to transparent would require the equivalent effort of just setting the android:listSelector property to my drawable, which, as I've said a few times now, does actually work. That link is a great article, by the way. Thank you Vikas